# How can I work with multibleproject with one Dockerfile?

Tags: c#, azure, docker, kubernetes, devops

My question is related to how to use Dockerfile in multiple projects.

when you look at src directory, you will see that all projects structure:

XXXX.Web.csproj under C:\src\test\src\XXXX.Web

Can you give me an advise,please?

my Dockerfile :

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 as build-image

WORKDIR /.
#COPY ["XXXX.sln", "./"]
COPY ./*/*.csproj ./
RUN for file in $(ls *.csproj); do mkdir -p ./${file%.*}/ && mv $file ./${file%.*}/; done

RUN dotnet restore

COPY . .



RUN dotnet publish ./XXXX.Web/XXXX.Web.csproj -o /publish/

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0

WORKDIR /publish

COPY --from=build-image /publish .

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://0.0.0.0:80"

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "XXXX.Web.dll"]
```

my .dockerignore:

```
node_modules
npm-debug.log
Dockerfile*
docker-compose*
.dockerignore
.git
.gitignore
.env
*/bin
*/obj
README.md 
LICENSE
.vscode
```

Please, Tell me what is wrong in my Dockerfile it producing "MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file." Why? I am open for any advise?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear "Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file", which means you need to provide one like `dotnet restore path/to/project.csproj` or if you want to restore the whole solution `dotnet restore path/to/solution.sln`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to take care of the location where you execute `dotnet restore` inside you docker file. You are missing a project or solution location.

```
dotnet restore <path>/<name>.csproj
```